# Date Range is not working in AWS ElasticSearch 6.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic search. I'm use elastic search to do some queries.

I want to find the products within a time window.
Here is the query:

Here is the mapping:

```
config = {
"settings": {
        "number_of_shards" :   1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    },
"mapping":{
  "topselling":{
        "properties":{
        "order_id":{"type":"long","store":"yes","index":"no"},
        "product":{"type":"string","store":"yes","index":"no"},
        "created_at":{"type":"date","store":"yes", "format":"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", "index":"analyzed"},

        }
  }
}
}

query={
"from" : 0,
"size" : 30,
"query":{
"range":{
    "created_at":{
        "gte":"2010-01-27 02:47:19",
        "lte":"2010-01-27 23:16:59",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    }
}
}
}
```

This is the code to search elasticsearch

```
response = es.search(index="topselling", doc_type="topselling", body=query)
```

I'm sure the data is in the cluster as I can get the data by query id.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should use `T` instead of space after `day`.

Comment: In your mapping you have `DD` while in your query you have `dd`, the latter is correct.